# openssl does not work in windows 2k19 nanoserver docker container

Tags: windows, docker, openssl, nano-server

I have copied openssl.exe from host to windows docker container (image: mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:ltsc2019),but it does not work

```
C:\config\openssl\openssl-1.1\x64\bin>openssl.exe version

C:\config\openssl\openssl-1.1\x64\bin>
```

Same command works fine on the host machine (Windows server 2k19)

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\openssl\openssl-1.1\x64\bin> .\openssl.exe version
OpenSSL 1.1.1s  1 Nov 2022
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\openssl\openssl-1.1\x64\bin>
```

What could be the issue here? and how do I access openssl in the container ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative, build openssl from souce code for windows on the ubuntu machine,

Refer steps from https://www.ssltrust.in/help/setup-guides/compile-openssl-from-source